# Darle color a una celda JTable de Netbeans comparando el Valor ingresado con el de la Base de datos

Tags: netbeans, jtable

Tengo un programa que me manda esta tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero lo siguiente:

-Si el **ID** es igual al número de **PUESTO** la(s) celda(s) con exactamente los mismos datos, su `celda`deberá cambiar de color a verde, de lo contrario serán rojos.

Es decir, si tengo dos datos, un ID: 10 y un PUESTO 10 del mismo trabajador

entonces solo la celda de la columna con el ID 10 se pondrá verde. Si el siguiente no tiene igual su ID con su PUESTO entonces será rojo.

***La pregunta es:***

*¿Cómo obtengo el valor de la columna *Puesto* para compararla con el valor del textbox y una vez con esos valores validar el cambiar de color de la celda?*

Implementé la clase:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class C_Render extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{

    public Component getTableCellRenderComponent(JTable table,Object value,boolean isSelected,boolean hasFocus,int row,int column){
        JLabel celda = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        if (value instanceof Integer) {
            if (column == 1) {
                Int valor = (Int)value;
                if (valor == 1) 
                    celda.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                else
                    celda.setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
        }
        return celda;
    };

}
```

Sé que este método va celda por celda

Mi lógica me dijo pasarle un **1** o **0**  como *cierto* o *falso*, validé en un método en Netbeans de la siguiente forma

```
public int validar(int v1, int v2){
  int res = 0;
  if(v1==v2)
   res=1;
  return res;
}
```

ya en la programación del diseño lo lleno con sus respectivos:

```
Integer.parseInt(txt1.getString());
```

Para que retornara el valor de 0 o 1 al Método de **C_Render** así obteniendo el color deseado a cada columna. Pero no sé cómo pasarle ese valor al método `C_Render();`

Ya que al momento de asignarle manualmente los argumentos me dice que el código no está diseñado para eso y me marca error.

Lo que no sé bien como implementar es ¿Cómo obtener el valor de cada celda para compararla y como asignarle el color solo a una celda que yo requiera?